# can not install apk after generate signed apk in Android studio

Tags: android, apk, sign

I want to publish my app to google play. So I follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

I created a keystore, and built `app-release.apk` successfully. But when I install APK to my device, it take error:

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb install ~/Downloads/libraries/LolliPin/app/app-release.apk 
[100%] /data/local/tmp/app-release.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

When upload to Developer Console, the site say app has not signed.

I try again using manual steps: jarsigned --> zipalign --> apksigner but it is not run.

Please tell me the solution. Many thanks!

UPDATE: when I verified the apk (created by android studio --> generate apk signed) by apksigned, it show error:

```
~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2$ ./apksigner verify /home/haitt22/test/app-release.apk 
DOES NOT VERIFY
ERROR: No JAR signatures
```

UPDATE 2: when i signed it using apksigner in build-tool, log:

```
/apksigner sign --ks /home/haitt22/test/test.jks /home/ubuntu/test/app-release-aligned.apk
Keystore password for signer #1: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner (in unnamed module @0x646d64ab) cannot access class sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.x509 to unnamed module @0x646d64ab
    at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.getSupportedAlgorithmId(V1SchemeSigner.java:625)
    at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.<clinit>(V1SchemeSigner.java:541)
    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.<init>(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:149)
    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.<init>(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:52)
    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine$Builder.build(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:902)
    at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.sign(ApkSigner.java:259)
    at com.android.apksig.ApkSigner.sign(ApkSigner.java:178)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:277)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
```

Comment: Installing APK to device does not require APK signing. You can install unsigned APK to device if your device's Developer Mode is enabled & install from untrusted source is allowed

Comment: Additionally, you can click "Run" or "Debug" in Android Studio to install & launch your App in your device, given that you have enabled USB Debugging

Comment: I want to upload to Google Play, so I need signed.

Comment: The APK running in device is different from uploading to Google Play. Don't mix up 2 versions.

Comment: Hi Raptor, OK they are different. But I upload this apk to Google Play, the site say my app is not signed. But I signed it using android studio (choose Generate signed APK in menu). Now I don't know how to sign it right.

Comment: It's weird that Android Studio cannot sign the APK properly. Have you updated Android Studio version to the latest version? Normally it will sign the App by following the instructions.

Comment: yes, i updated android studio to the latest version (2.3) and using latest build tool (25.0.2). hic.

Comment: Failures in apksigner due to access to sun.security.* are a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=238978) caused by apksigner using Oracle/Sun private API which is no longer permitted in Java 9. A workaround is to use Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that, both *Jar signature* and *APK signature* are checked:

[image: Both need to be checked]

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenJDK 8. Java 9 is causing this problem